# Cannot select values via VRM_SET_VALUES?

Tags: abap, dynpro

I made Listbox on screen using function `VRM_SET_VALUES`. It works normal, but I can't choose field from the list.

[image: SAP GUI dropdown listbox]

Have I forgotten something?

```
DATA: BEGIN OF gs_screen1100,
        db_flight(40) TYPE c,
      END OF gs_screen1100.

MODULE init_listbox OUTPUT.
  DATA:
    ls_value  TYPE vrm_value,
    lt_values TYPE vrm_values.

  SELECT carrid, connid
    FROM sflight
    WHERE carrid = 'LH'
    INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_sflight).

  CLEAR lt_values.
  LOOP AT lt_sflight ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_sflight>).
    ls_value-key = <fs_sflight>-carrid.
    ls_value-text = <fs_sflight>-connid.
    APPEND ls_value TO lt_values.
  ENDLOOP.

  CALL FUNCTION 'VRM_SET_VALUES'
    EXPORTING
      id     = 'GS_SCREEN1100-DB_FLIGHT'
      values = lt_values.
ENDMODULE.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer on answer.sap.com.
The error is due to how you fill the list of values, **KEY should be unique**.

`ls_value-key = <fs_sflight>-carrid` is not a unique. It will store "LH" in the screen field and "LH" represents many entries, the first one is shown. The code below is one of the solutions.

```
LOOP AT lt_sflight ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_sflight>).
    ls_value-key = <fs_sflight>-carrid && <fs_sflight>-connid.
    ls_value-text = <fs_sflight>-carrid && ` ` && <fs_sflight>-connid.
    APPEND ls_value TO lt_values.
  ENDLOOP.
```

Answer (score 0):

use global name in top for your listbox. and read global value